# android development with low ram

Tags: android, performance

I want to write android applications but my computer is a Intel core duo 3GHr with 2GB RAM (1.86 usage) and 64 bit Operating system (windows 7 professional)
As I understand Android studio will be difficult to run with this ram.
My question is that can I use eclipse or netbeans and  It will be ok to run with this ram?
Also as I understand I need to download Android Studio to have the android sdk?

Comment: yes 4Gb ram is minimum for Android Studio use Eclipse.. better option... or upgrade your PC

Comment: it will be difficult to develop with eclipse as you will have to constantly struggle with configurations. It will be great if you can upgrade your hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Yes in Eclipse will be good for this configuration, you can create a project and run, but dont run your application on emulator use you real device(mobile).

Comment: So I have also to download the studio to download also the android jdk?

Comment: Its Java jdk go to oracle website to download, no need of downloading android studio.

Comment: I downloaded the jdk 8 of oracle,I Install the plugin of Netbeans for android and it needs the android sdk also,

Comment: yes, you have to download android sdk and place the sdk path in eclipse